# Does the here-api support geographic data files (gdf)?

Tags: here-api

I'm currently working on a webapplication that uses the here-api for some routing tasks. As far as I know there is only the option to pick either geojson or xml as response file format. In the future we might need to talk to a third party software that is only accepting gdf as input. Is there a possibility to get gdf responses directly from the here-api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO, currently Here API supports only geojson and xml format. If you are paid customer then you can contact the sales team(selfservesupport@here.com) to see if they can provide support for your usecase in future.